# strsplit in R: How do I split one-column data separated by comma into multiple columns?

Tags: r, strsplit

I am reading data from a website: https://raw.github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/master/02-Exploration/data/01_heights_weights_genders.csv

(1) At first I attempted to read the data directly into R with the following code:

```
raw_data <- read.table("https://raw.github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/master/02-Exploration/data/01_heights_weights_genders.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

But I received the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : unsupported URL scheme
```

So I simply copied the data into a .csv file.  I saved this file as "Raw_Data.csv" in a directory.  The data is, however, all in one column.

(2) I read this file into R via the following code

```
raw_data <- read.csv("Raw_Data.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

What I would like to do is split this one column into three, with the column names as "Gender", "Height", "Weight".  What I tried was this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(raw_data)){
    raw_data$Gender[i] <- strsplit(raw_data$Gender[i], ",")[[1]][1]
    raw_data$Height[i] <- strsplit(raw_data$Height[i], ",")[[1]][2]
    raw_data$Weight[i] <- strsplit(raw_data$Weight[i], ",")[[1]][3]
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error in strsplit(raw_data$Gender[i], ",") : non-character argument
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't see why it should be in one column. Did you try and save it as a csv from Excel? Can you try copying it into notepad and saving it from there instead?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.  When I type    class(raw_data[,1]), I get "character" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be it was because of quotes,

try

```
raw_data <- read.csv("Raw_Data.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quotes="\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read the data into R with 3 columns just fine.

I'm not sure how you saved the data into a .csv file, but I copied the data right into Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), saved it as a text file, and read it into R with read.csv("filename.txt").

Comment: I'll definitely do that, and thank you for the help.  However, I would like to know how to solve this "type" of problem, where I can split one column into three with this dataset.  What I did was simply go to the website and press Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, and copied into excel directly saving as a .csv.

Comment: That happens because Excel doesn't parse text pasted into it- if you look at the Excel file that you tried to read in, you'll see that the first column holds an entire row's worth of data. If you want a .csv file, you can paste the data into notepad, save it as a text file, and then open it with Excel, choosing the comma as the delimiter